# Android ListView Adapter OnClick selects wrong Position

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I went through all the answers and questions on StackOverflow regarding this but I can't seem to edit my code to rectify the issue.

Basically, I have a button that needs an OnClick listener set inside the ListView Adapter. Each row has a unique ID and the wrong id gets selected when I click on the button, which basically means its selecting the wrong position.

Here's my Adapter code:

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ActivityObject> actList = new ArrayList<ActivityObject>();
    String currActID;

    //More code

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;
        final ActivityObject act = actList.get(position);
        currActID = act.getId();

        if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_picture, parent, false);
             holder = new Holder();
             holder.comment = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentbutton);
             convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
             holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                //Log.d("Check",currActID);
                //Selects the Wrong ID
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, CommentActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
             }
       });

       return convertView;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong guys? Can you point out the mistake please.

Comment: Once Check this List view adapter [this](http://javatechig.com/android/loading-image-asynchronously-in-android-listview) may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String currActID = act.getId();
```

instead of making it global.

why? because simply currActID will always equal the last position unless u scroll then it will again becomes the id of the scrolled last position.

Comment: Hahahaa that was it!! Sometimes you need a swift kick in the backside for forgetting the basics :D Will accept this in 10 minutes

Comment: yeah it is. however if it was the right please accept it so it becomes available to others in the future.

Comment: Yeah mate I will. Stackoverflow wants me to wait another 10 minutes cos I posted just now :) Thanks man!!